# Why is the pre-population not working in Dynamics CRM?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-365

The tentative goal is to allow [form pre-population](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IW6_jDW2qDw) from Project entity to related Document entity. Notice that both are custom entities. The relationship between Project and Document is set properly:

[image: relationship between Project and Document]

And the mappings for this relationship are also set:

[image]

However, when we try to create a new Document for an existing Project. The fields are empty:

[image]

Why is the pre-population not working?

Answer (score 1):

The out of box workings for mapping only works in the case of creating a record from a grid.  If you're not doing this, you won't get the mapping.